# Mirror plugin in unity ,problems with server and client authority

Tags: unity-game-engine, mirror

I'm using mirror.And my player interact with an interactable object, then create a gun for the player and set a property in player's scripts.But i get warning saying that

```
 Command System.Void M4_Interact::Interact(UnityEngine.GameObject) called on M4_Interact without authority.
```

The first image tells that i use raycast to check interact,and assign authority,then into the second image's function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1I37.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CCsE.png)

If i use functions or other things wrongly or any other mistake.